# Time Formatting in D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 line plot that I am plotting out the dates by month/day. The problem is the x-axis defaults to showing year "1900" at the axis origin. Is there a way I can change this to default to "January" instead of "1900" as my lines are where I am highlighting different years. My plnkr is below

http://plnkr.co/edit/22Jc4Nte0WWLQzT7a9lr?p=preview

I'm assuming the change is made in either of the below lines, however, I'm not sure the way to change it.

```
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
```

or

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `tickFormat` for the x-axis using `%b` so it knows only to display abbreviated month names. Check [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md#timeFormat) for time formatting options in d3.

```
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b"))
  );
```

Check the updated Plunkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/7ZUSQJduYPL5VNAxBG5u?p=preview

Comment: Awesome! Thanks you so much and thanks for the link to time formats as well =)